# Change the width of the layout and align to the right side while clicking the button

Tags: android

I have to develop an Android application in that when I click the button in the map view, the view should shrinks to a particular width and should align to the right side. But when I click the button, the width of the mapview is reducing but it is left aligning. I tried a lot to align it to left side, but I couldn’t do it. Any idea plz. The figures are attached.[image]

[image]

Comment: Do u really need resize MapView? The simplest solution is to add your left panel covering MapView using RelativeLayout and make it visible/invisible depending on the state of your button.

Comment: I really want to resize MapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if `MapView` has a non standard behavior, but I can think of different ways:

- having the `MapView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and using `android:alignParentRight="true"`
- having the `MapView` inside a `LinearLayout`, with before it another view (I suspect you'll have one in the cyan part) set as wrap_content, and the `MapView` set with weight=1. (switching the first view between GONE and VISIBLE would do the job)
- setting a left margin on the `MapView`.